# Is this an example of a Neapolitan chord?

Tags: theory, chords, harmony, chord-theory, chord-progressions

[image]

The chord that goes on the fourth and fifth bars of my attachment above looks like a Neapolitan chord.  The excerpt is the second movement of Beethoven's Symphony No. 3: *Marcia funebre Adagio assai*.  (The C at the end of the fifth bar as a passing tone)  In fact, the chord progression appears as if it is I - N - V<sup>6</sup> in C major.  (C - D♭ - G/B)  Am I right?

Comment: @DavidBowling // http://ks.imslp.net/files/imglnks/usimg/1/11/IMSLP01054-Beethoven-Liszt_Symphony-3.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link! For other viewers, that link is the Liszt piano transcription of Beethoven's Symphony No. 3 in E Flat Major "Eroica", and this excerpt is of the funeral march movement's transition from the trio back to the minor-key outer march section.

Comment: what do you mean by "outer march"? Is it "inner march" - "trio" - "outer march"? (As it is written in A - B - A structure)

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya - No, I mean "outer march"-"trio"-"outer march", with the trio being the "inner march".

Comment: Oh... I see.  (The trio (inner march) sounds like a waltz to me, and is brighter and more heavenly compared to the outer march, which is sorrowful and tragic - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beethoven_and_C_minor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a Neapolitan chord. Because of the arpeggio, it's not in the usual position (F-A♭-D♭-F). The last three notes are D♭-C-B which is a common melodic figure over a N6-V transition.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say yes: Beethoven is kind of on the nose here and outlines a D flat major chord in the 5th bar of the excerpt. It's followed by dominant-function leading tones. Right after that and outside of the excerpt, G's play, and then the rest of the piece continues with C minor chord figurations. Sounds like a Neapolitan chord that properly resolves to me.

Interpretation ambiguity can still reign, though: the 3rd and 4th bars of that excerpt can easily be interpreted as outlining an F minor chord, IMO, as long as you ditch the E in the third bar early in.